# Image strip won't scale through CSS attributes

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image strip that is quite large. 130560 x 1080 I want to load it into an image tag and have the parent div used as a view port to only see 1 portion of the image at a time.

The problem I am having is that if I do *not* specify the height and the width of the image then the image displays. However, if I do specify a height and width such as width=54442 height=432 then the image disappears. The purpose is to scale it to 40%. I have tried changing it through CSS, attributes and the interactively in the Chrome debugger, but in all cases any value for height will make the image disappear.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #imgContainer
            {
                width: 768px;
                height: 432px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imgContainer">
            <img src="complete.png" id='montage'  height="432px"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used this technique on smaller jpgs, but haven't tried it on a PNG nor on a file of this size.

For anyone wanting to try this out here is the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sWWl4f5UpESGEtRUdYbklQX0U/view?usp=sharing
Warning size is 12MB.

Comment: are you after something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c2vtt0n3/

Answer (score 0):

a `img` element is a inline element, set its CSS style to `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to have it receive its scaling.

You can also set the width with `width="54442"` (without px) percentages work as well.

---

**Offtopic:**

You're mixing different quotation marks, I'd recommend only using " in html, to keep it clean.
Large images takes a lot of loading, maybe you should reduce its size drastically, of course it doesn't really matter if this is just a private project.